# Firefox não está rodando o metodo .css() do Jquery, como corrigir?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Estou usando esse script [jasny-bootstrap.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.js), nesse trecho de codigo

```html
<head>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.js"></script>

</head><body>
<div class="container col-md-6 fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput" id="btnImagem">
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top: 45px;">
    <span class="btn btn-info btn-file"><span>Imagem</span>
    <input type="file" />
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" id="imagem" style="padding-top: 35px;">
    <span class="fileinput-preview" style="max-height: 68px;"></span>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

O problema é que no Chrome a imagem que é inserida fica com o max-height = 68px, e quando vou no Firefox a imagem não fica com o max-lenght.(Nao redimensiona e deve redimensionar como no Chrome)

Como resolver esse probleminha?

Estou tendo a impressão que esse trecho do js não roda no Firefox

```
 if (preview.css('max-height') != 'none') $img.css('max-height', parseInt(preview.css('max-height'), 10) - parseInt(preview.css('padding-top'), 10) - parseInt(preview.css('padding-bottom'), 10)  - parseInt(preview.css('border-top'), 10) - parseInt(preview.css('border-bottom'), 10))
```

Alguma solução?

Comment: Parece estar tudo bem aqui...

Comment: @JorgeB. vc rodou no Chrome e no Firefox?

Comment: Nos dois e deu bem...

Comment: entao eh meu firefox, mas como tratar isso pra que nao ocorra no cliente ter esses erros? tipo no Chrome a imagem eh redimensionada corretamente e no firefox nao, como tratar vc sabe? @JorgeB. poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: afinal não funciona no firefox...

Comment: a questão é que no Firefox a imagem nao redimensiona, nao seta o `max-height` na tag `<img>` que é gerada pelo jasny, @JorgeB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é um bug do `.css`, na verdade é uma característica que é diferente no Firefox e no Webkit (ou Blink) que por padrão o Webkit possui na propriedade `border:` o valor `0px none rgb(51, 51, 51)` em qualquer elemento, já no Firefox (gecko) o `border:` sempre é vazio.

Isto é um padrão (default) de CSS do Chrome (e acredito que dos navegadores baseados em Safari também).

Ou seja ao pegar com `.css("border-bottom")` ele retorna vazio no Firefox e o `parseInt` não faz a conversão de vazio, ele retorna `NaN`, qualquer calculo matemático com `NaN` vai retornar `NaN`, por isto no Firefox não funciona.

Como no Chrome `.css("border-bottom")` ele retorna `0px none rgb(51, 51, 51)` o `parseInt` o converte pra `0` então o calculo matemático irá funcionar.

O problema não é do jQuery ou do Firefox, o problema é da biblioteca `jasny-bootstrap`

> **NOTA:**
>
> Como citei antes eu enviei um pullrequest https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/pull/444 pra corrigirem o código e finalmente ele foi aprovado https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/commit/feea0e59b58cab170aefa5608ee976117c4b4f4b (depois de quase 3 meses), ainda não foi lançado um "release", mas é possivel baixar diretamente do repositório os arquivos da pasta:
>
> - https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/tree/master/dist

<s>Uma breve solução é fazer isto:</s>

```
    // if parent has max-height, using `(max-)height: 100%` on child doesn't take padding and border into account
    if (preview.css('max-height') != 'none') {
        var mh = parseInt(preview.css('max-height'), 10) || 0
        var pt = parseInt(preview.css('padding-top'), 10) || 0
        var pb = parseInt(preview.css('padding-bottom'), 10) || 0
        var bt = parseInt(preview.css('border-top'), 10) || 0
        var bb = parseInt(preview.css('border-bottom'), 10) || 0

        $img.css('max-height', mh - pt - pb - bt - bb);
    }
```

Comment: Correto obrigado creio eu q resolvera aqui

Comment: @TiagoFerezin finalmente eles aceitaram o pullrequest que enviei, atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Inclui a referência ao jQuery antes do Bootstrap e Jasny:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Com o código actual, se utilizares a consola do *browser* vês que ambas as bibliotecas não foram devidamente carregadas devido à falta de jQuery (requisito obrigatório):

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
>
> Uncaught Error: Jasny Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: infelizmente nao mudou nada

Comment: esse erro nao da no meu firefox, nao aponta nenhum erro, apenas nao atibui o style ao img q eu quero

Comment: ja alterei agora roda no Chrome e dps roda no Firefox pra ver a diferenca, eu quero que ocorre da maneira que fica no Chrome @w00t

Comment: Ok, já vi a diferença. Podes mostrar a parte do script jQuery onde fazes o tratamento da imagem?

Comment: acho que eh esse eh o q ta dentro do jasny `// if parent has max-height, using `(max-)height: 100%` on child doesn't take padding and border into account
        if (preview.css('max-height') != 'none') $img.css('max-height', parseInt(preview.css('max-height'), 10) - parseInt(preview.css('padding-top'), 10) - parseInt(preview.css('padding-bottom'), 10)  - parseInt(preview.css('border-top'), 10) - parseInt(preview.css('border-bottom'), 10))
        
        preview.html($img)` @w00t

Comment: Eu nao faço no meu jquery, eu to deixando o jasny fazer, porem queria saber como tratar isso.